# How can i assign xapth value to WebElement which are retrieved from Excel sheet in string formate

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have created an excel sheet which contains Xpath for username and password field.

I have retrieved those value from excel and stored them in String variable

xapth value retrieved from excel sheet

```
String xpath = xpath.getContents();
```

i wana to send above value to below WebElement email instead of hardcoded xpath

```
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='j_username']"));
```

How can i send the xapth value from string variable to WebElement statement?

Comment: If you found any answer which satisfied your need then don't forget to accept the answer. If may help the other

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have one xpath e.g. `//div[@class='abc']/input` in your Excel sheet in cell 0 0

then first you need to read that cell and store its value in a string.

To get string value method is

```
String usernameXpath = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
```

Then pass it as :

```
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.xpath(usernameXpath));
```

Below is sample code to read data from excel based on known cell

```
public class ReadExcel 
{
    FileInputStream fis;
    XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    XSSFSheet sheet;

    public ReadExcel() throws IOException
    {
        // Read Excel File
        fis = new FileInputStream(new File("src/test/resources/SiteTestData.xlsx"));
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        // To get Sheet 1
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    }

    public String getCellData(int rowNum, int colNum)
    {
        return sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colNum).getStringCellValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: @MSD, If this answer is helpful then please do `accept`